# Use a button instead of a wave

Tags: riddle, word, letters

This recipe does not make any sense but each step has its own by-product.

1. Add a letter and you'll have the shortest and the most ambiguous answer.
2. Add a letter and you'll have 47 machine-guns.
3. Add a letter and you'll have a software that goes beyond.
4. Add a letter and you'll be splitting logs.
5. Add a letter and you'll have a shelter in the woods.
6. Add a wave and you'll have a store.

Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The final answer is

> RadioShack

The title

> is a reference to a [radio button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button)

1. Add a letter and you'll have the shortest and the most ambiguous answer.

> **K** - an abbreviation for 'OK'

2. Add a letter and you'll have 47 machine-guns.

> **AK** - ak47 is a machine gun

3. Add a letter and you'll have a software that goes beyond.

> **ACK** - <strike>an [acknowledgement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acknowledgement_(data_networks)) in data networks</strike> What the OP intended was [this](https://beyondgrep.com/).

4. Add a letter and you'll be splitting logs.

> **HACK**

5. Add a letter and you'll have a shelter in the woods.

> **SHACK**

6. Add a wave and you'll have a store.

> **[RadioShack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RadioShack)** - (thanks @sousben) a type of wave is a radio wave

Comment: That was quick. Good job! The first answer is not right though. I let that sink in to see if you can think of something else. FYI, the software is [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/)

Comment: @A.D. oh, I got ACK for a different reason :P (see edit). I assume the first answer must therefore by K - as in an abbreviation for okay? Also is the title supposed to mean something?

Comment: You're right for K. The title was another idea I've got to introduce the radio part. There is radio button on web pages. That's all.

Comment: @A.D. ah someone said it might be that in chat. Nice puzzle!

Comment: Can you add a letter if you don't have any yet?

Comment: @Acccumulation I guess, adding 1 to nothing gives 1...